# Why is WLED_SW connected to supply

Tags: power, buck, boost

I am usin this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps68470.pdf and in the schematic they tell us to connect the WLED_SW through an inductor to an input supply. I though the WLED_SW(switching node) is generally driven by the buck itself. Is there any reason why I need to connect it to the input?

Comment: which schematic?

Comment: Block diagram on 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you asking. WLED_SW is the switch pin of the converter for switching external inductor. That is exactly what it is there for - to switch an inductor, which is part of the **boost** circuit. The buck circuit has its own inductor and capacitors.

Comment: Why is the other end of WLED_SW connected to input power supply? Is this the way it is normally arranged?

Comment: The other end of the _inductor_ is connected to power input. This is where it is supposed to go. Just google "boost converter ic" and "buck converter ic" and compare schematics with boost and buck connections in the datasheet. Boost inductor goes to input, buck inductor goes to output.